# Nested CSS calc() working in JS, but not inline

Tags: css

I'm trying to perform a `calc()` with two calculations in a nested `calc()`, which works in JS (since it renders as a single number), but not inline, so I'm trying to find a workaround. If I remove the subtraction or the multiplication, it works, but I need both.

```
<div>Hello World</div>

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc( 10% + ( 8 - 10 * 0.15px ) );
}
```

- The `10` value is an Ember computed property.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that shows your css and html.

Comment: @t.niese Sure, just updated. Hope that's enough

Comment: Please describe what the calculation is to do as 8 -10 * 0.15px makes no sense as 8 is unitless.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "works in JS".

With `calc` you cannot subtract/add unit-less numbers nor multiply two numbers that have a unit.

The problem with your code is that first it evaluates:

`10 * 0.15px` = `1.5px`

But then it tries to do:

`8 - 1.5px` with it can't compute because 8 has  no unit.

You should do something like:

`left: calc( 10% + ( 8px - 10px * 0.15 ) );`

Or put proper parentheses for precedence:

`left: calc( 10% + ((8 - 10) * 0.15px ) );`

Depends on what you want to achieve (:

Comment: I explained why it works in JS, since the nested calculation renders as a single number. Here's an example: `calc(20% + 5px)`. The first option you gave is not applicable because only `0.15` can be `px`, not the `{{var}}`, as in my example, and the second one's result was slightly off and not the same as when it's calculated in JS.

Comment: There is not `{{var}}` in your example.

It all boils down to these two rules I mentioned, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a unit like `px` or `%` on that 8. When you want it "inline" do you mean hardcoded into the `<div>` like so?:

```
<div style=`left: calc( ${x}% + ( 8px - ${y} * 0.15px ))`>Hello World</div>
```

If so, how do you suppose those variables get a number? The example below uses JavaScript method `.setProperty()` to the `.style` property of the `<div>` thereby an inline style. In DevTools it looks like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: calc(80% + 7.7px);">Hello World</div>
```

Note, the value is a template literal with the variables interpolated. Is `{{var}}` Handlebars? React? IDK the only tag posted is CSS. Also, I left `y` without a unit because it'll work with `0.15px` as a valid multiplier.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

let x = 80;
let y = 2;

div.style.setProperty('left', `calc( ${x}% + ( 8px - ${y} * 0.15px ))`);
```

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div style='position:absolute;'>Hello World</div>
</main>
```